# Input number section function only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have one function for the number input box come with `+` and `-` button on the sides, and copy the code in my `shopify` theme which I use. But that function only show one time. But I need those apply to all the product offers.

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.bootstrapNumber = function (options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        upClass: 'default',
        downClass: 'default',
        center: true
    }, options);

    return this.each(function (e) {
        var self = $(this);
        var clone = self.clone();

        var min = self.attr('min');
        var max = self.attr('max');

        function setText(n) {
            if ((min && n < min) || (max && n > max)) {
                return false;
            }

            clone.focus().val(n);
            return true;
        }

        var group = $("<div class='input-group'></div>");
        var down = $("<button type='button'>-</button>").attr('class', 'btn btn-' + settings.downClass).click(function () {
            setText(parseInt(clone.val()) - 1);
        });
        var up = $("<button type='button'>+</button>").attr('class', 'btn btn-' + settings.upClass).click(function () {
            setText(parseInt(clone.val()) + 1);
        });
        $("<span class='input-group-btn'></span>").append(down).appendTo(group);
        clone.appendTo(group);
        if (clone) {
            clone.css('text-align', 'center');
        }
        $("<span class='input-group-btn'></span>").append(up).appendTo(group);

        // remove spins from original
        clone.prop('type', 'text').keydown(function (e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                return;
            }
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            var n = parseInt(clone.val() + c);

            //if ((min && n < min) || (max && n > max)) {
            //    e.preventDefault();
            //}
        });

        clone.prop('type', 'text').blur(function (e) {
            var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
            var n = parseInt(clone.val() + c);
            if ((min && n < min)) {
                setText(min);
            }
            else if (max && n > max) {
                setText(max);
            }
        });


        self.replaceWith(group);
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are setting the class attribute using `attr` instead of in the `$()` call for the `up` and `down` vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you initialise the function ?

Your problem certainly lies there...
Because it works using this:

```
$('input').bootstrapNumber();
```

**[See my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/hfyy5q2r/) that includes your exact unmodified script.**

Comment: I found your initialisation... On lines 729 - 730 of the view source. You use an `id` : `#colorful`. Use a class! An `id` must be unique anyway... Which is not the case in your page.

Comment: Use `$(".input-group-btn input").bootstrapNumber({ upClass: 'success',
 downClass: 'danger'  });` on line 730...  Remove line 729 :`$('#after').bootstrapNumber();`¸.

Comment: If I add the line you point out:  $('input').bootstrapNumber(); it get worse.

Comment: $("[name='checkbox2']").change(function() {
 if(!confirm('Do you wanna cancel me!')) {
  this.checked = true;
 }
});

$('#after').bootstrapNumber();
$('#colorful').bootstrapNumber({
 upClass: 'success',
 downClass: 'danger'
});

Comment: The simpliest way to solve it WILL be to add a class to the input you want to target. Something like in my Fiddle `class="bootstrapN"`. Then use : `$(".bootstrapN").bootstrapNumber();` Remove all duplicates `id="after"` by the way. ;)

Comment: unfortunately, it can't be fixed

Comment: I see you added `bootstrapN` class... But you still use `$('#after').bootstrapNumber();
$('#colorful').bootstrapNumber({...` on lines 729 - 730. Use : `$(".bootstrapN").bootstrapNumber();`

Comment: let me double check and removed all the id="after"

Comment: Oh Yeah! ;) Cheers!